Why the function new() inside a class is referenced when constructing an object?
Why function new() inside a class is referenced when constructing an object?
For example:
class BusTran;
 int data=32;
endclass : BusTran

class Driver;
 BusTran bt;
 function new(); // Driver’s new function
  bt = new(); // Call the BusTran new function
 endfunction
endclass : Driver

module tb;
 Driver f1;
 initial begin
  f1=new();
 end
endmodule

(modified example from the book "systemverilog for verification" page 73)
My question is;
When the following is preformed:

initial begin
f1=new();
end;

Firstly, why the class get's "accessed" with the simple commend "new()"? I guess it's because of the handler, but I feel like there's more to it..
And secondly, why "function new()" is executed?
In addition (following the second question), does "new()" calls the the function or it is called automatically when the class Driver is pointed?
Lastly, why there's no "return" commend in  "function new()"?

The constructor new is a reserved keyword in SystemVerilog and has some builtin special behaviors. You cannot specify a function return type because it always returns a handle to a class object of the class type being constructed. And you do return a handle because it always returns that handle.
If you do not declare a function new in your class then SystemVerilog inserts one for you. You must explicitly call new to have a class object constructed. It is never automatically constructed.
And finally the syntax requires that you call new() as the RHS of an assignment to class variable on the LHS. The constructor gets called like a static function class_type::new()

Thank your for you reply, Sir. Could you please explain why "function new()" is accesses? In my understanding when "f1=new()" is read by the compiler, firstly a class object is created and secondly the class members is set to default (no data members in this case for Driver class). But why "function new()" is "triggered"? Usually we need to call the function, for example with "f1.new()" (if "new" was the function's name).

Updated answer. f1.new() would not make any sense because f1 is null before the object gets constructed.

No, I'm saying to construct the object with 'f1=new; f1.new();' the first one construct the Driver class and the second one call the function to construct the BusTran class
